# How to configure nginx for wordpress

Tags: nginx

I'm having a working nginx, php-fpm and other php packages and mysql. I've extracted wordpress-3.4.2.zip in /usr/local/nginx/html/blog. When I visit localhost/blog I get "500 internal server error". Is there any special configuration that needs to be done for nginx to make wordpress work?

Comment: error logs? configs? php configured under nginx as what?

Comment: php is configured under nginx as php-fpm. Configs are all OK and valid.

Comment: You can configure nginx with WordPress with easyengine (http://goo.gl/Wzidcu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided info by you is SO huge... so i can only advice.

1. run nginx - it works? goto step 2
2. run nginx with php, see info.php with phpinfo() insie? goto step 3.
3. run nginx with php and global host rewrite to this index script. It works ? go to step 4.
4. run nginx with php and anabled error reporting (logs/display anything). do typo in script. see error? good. now you can TEST whats problem you have with php.

Generaly this is nginx issue not the wordpress. please back to us whan you willl do all these steps.

3) Script code and sample [Nginx Configs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#WordPress_Multisite_Subdirectory_rules)

```
<?php var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
```

4) PHP bugly code.

```
<?php vardump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>
```

NGINX (change error log location if you want.)

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/host1.php.error.log";
```

Comment: Step 1 and 2 work. I don't understand what does step 3 and 4 mean. Can you provide a ready-made script that does step 3 and 4.

Comment: moment let me update answer

Comment: Hey, you shoudl understand what you doing. Not just do something. So $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] return NULL. Back to your php envoiropment debug, you not passing variables to php.

Comment: ok. we have php errors in step 4. it's OK. now back to step 3. you should organize on nginx rewrite system - it means that requsting site.com/test, site.com/demotest, site.com/onemore/test/ should output you a /test, /demotest, /onemore/test/... you need to tweak your nginx options to do that. after yo fix it we can continue with WP.

Comment: googling for "nginx php-fpm rewrite" will give you enough samples. just skip all install sections and read carefuly about configuring a rewrite. don't forget about Codex article. Just you understand **location** principes - it look amazingly simple for you.

Comment: Just got it. I went back to step 3. Now when I visit http://localhost I get output as string(1) "/" and visiting http://localhost?q=test give me  string(8) "/?q=test"  as output. Is it correct?

Comment: try with more exmaples =) (and yes that correct). here is one more tutorial to configure wp under nginx - http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress. more simple IMHO than that one you have in wp codex.